# Why am I getting "sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 5, and there are 4 supplied" error

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am running this code to make some kind of simulation of a real life library simulation. It makes you able to add books and also change them on the database.

```
from kütüphane import *

print("*" * 30)
print("""
      
Kütüphane programına hoşgeldiniz
      
İşlemler:
      
1.Kitapları Göster
2.Kitap Sorgulama
3.Kitap Ekle
4.Kitap Sil
5.Baskı Yükselt

Çıkmak için 'q' ya basın
      """)
print("*" * 30)

kütüphane = Kütüphane()

while True:
    işlem = input("İşlem giriniz")
    
    if (işlem == "q"):
        print("Program sonlandırılıyor")
        print("Yine bekleriz")
        break
    
    elif(işlem == "1"):
        kütüphane.kitapları_göster()
    
    elif(işlem == "2"):
        isim = input("Kitap ismi giriniz")
        print("Kitap sorgulanıyor")
        time.sleep(1)
        kütüphane.kitap_sorgula(isim,)
        
    elif(işlem == "3"):
        isim = input("İsim:")
        yazar = input("Yazar:")
        yayınevi = input("Yayınevi:")
        tür = input("Tür:")
        baskı = int(input("Baskı:"))
        
        yeni_kitap = Kitap(isim, yazar, yayınevi, tür, baskı)
        
        print("Kitap ekleniyor")
        time.sleep(1)
        kütüphane.kitap_ekle(yeni_kitap,)
        
        print("Kitap eklendi")
        
    elif(işlem == "4"):
        isim = input("Hangi kitabı silmek istiyorsunuz?")
        
        cevap = input("Emin misiniz? (E/H)")
        
        if (cevap == "E" or cevap == "e"):
            print("Kitap siliniyor")
            time.sleep(1)
            kütüphane.kitap_sil(isim,)
            print("Kitap silindi")
            
        if (cevap == "H" or cevap == "h"):
            pass
        
        else:
            print("Geçersiz işlem")
    
    elif(işlem == "5"):
        isim = input("Hangi kitabın baskısını yükseltmek istiyorsunuz?")
        
        kütüphane.baskı_yükselt(isim,)
        print("Baskı yükseltiliyor")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Baskı yükseltildi")
    
    else:
        print("Geçersiz işlem")
```

The code of the module I am using is:

```
import sqlite3
import time

class Kitap():
    
    def __init__(self,isim,yazar,yayınevi,tür,baskı):
        self.isim = isim
        self.yazar = yazar
        self.yayınevi = yayınevi
        self.tür = tür
        self.baskı = baskı
        
    def __str__(self):
        return("Kitap ismi: {}\nYazar: {}\nYayınevi: {}\nTür: {}\nBaskı{}".format(self.isim, self.yazar, self.yayınevi, self.tür, self.baskı))
    
class Kütüphane():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.bağlantı_oluştur()
        
    def bağlantı_oluştur(self):
        
        self.bağlantı = sqlite3.connect("kütüphane.db")
        self.cursor = self.bağlantı.cursor()
        
        sorgu = "Create Table if not exists kitaplar (isim TEXT, yazar TEXT, yayınevi TEXT, tür TEXT, baskı INT)"
        
        self.cursor.execute(sorgu,)
        self.bağlantı.commit()
    
    def bağlantıyı_kes(self):
        self.bağlantı.close
        
    def kitapları_göster(self):
        
        sorgu = "Select * from kitaplar"
        
        self.cursor.execute(sorgu,)
        
        kitaplar = self.cursor.fetchall()
        
        if (len(kitaplar) == 0):
            print("kütüphanede kitap bulunmuyor")
            
        else:
            for i in kitaplar:
                kitap = Kitap(i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3], i[4])
                print(kitap)
                
    def kitap_sorgula(self, isim):
        
        sorgu = "Select * from kitaplar where isim = ?"
        
        self.cursor.execute(sorgu,(isim,))
        
        kitaplar = self.cursor.fetchall()
        
        if (len(kitaplar) == 0):
            print("Böyle bir kitap bulunmuyor")
        
        else:
            kitap = Kitap(kitaplar[0][0], kitaplar[0][1], kitaplar[0][2], kitaplar[0][3], kitaplar[0][4])
            
            print(kitap)
            
    def kitap_ekle(self,kitap):
        sorgu = "Insert into kitaplar Values(?,?,?,?,?)"
            
        self.cursor.execute(sorgu, (kitap.yazar,kitap.yayınevi,kitap.tür,kitap.baskı,))
        self.bağlantı.commit()
        
    def kitap_sil(self,isim):
            
        sorgu = "Delete from kitaplar where isim= ?"
            
        self.cursor.execute(sorgu,(isim,))
        self.bağlantı.commit()

    def baskı_yükselt(self,isim):
            
        sorgu = "Select * from kitaplar where isim = ?"
            
        self.cursor.execute(sorgu, (isim,))
            
        kitaplar = self.cursor.fetchall()
            
        if (len(kitaplar) == 0):
            print("Böyle bir kitap bulunmuyor")
                
        else:
            baskı = kitaplar[0][4]
            baskı += 1
                
            sorgu2 = "Update kitaplar set baskı = ? where isim = ?"
                
            self.cursor.execute(sorgu2,(baskı, isim))
                
            self.bağlantı.commit()
```

When I try to run the `kitap_ekle()` function it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Python kodlama egzersizleri\Sqlite veritabanı\Kodlama egzersizleri\proje_deneme.py", line 50, in <module>
    kütüphane.kitap_ekle(yeni_kitap,)
  File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Python kodlama egzersizleri\Sqlite veritabanı\Kodlama egzersizleri\kütüphane.py", line 69, in kitap_ekle
    self.cursor.execute(sorgu, (kitap.yazar,kitap.yayınevi,kitap.tür,kitap.baskı,))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 5, and there are 4 supplied.
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

In this code segment

```py
def kitap_ekle(self,kitap):
    sorgu = "Insert into kitaplar Values(?,?,?,?,?)"
        
    self.cursor.execute(sorgu, (kitap.yazar,kitap.yayınevi,kitap.tür,kitap.baskı,))
```

the insert statement has five value placeholders, but only four values are passed to `self.cursor.execute`.  The number of placeholders must be equal to the number of values passed to the `execute` method.